# OPENGL C# Change Object View

Tags: c#, opengl

i have some object in opengl, the object is view at x position, i want to make it view at y position how to make it?? 
that is the code

```
 Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);


for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 360); iogl = (iogl + 3))
            {
                Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 25);
                Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 25);
                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 35);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
        {
            //Tabung
            Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 6);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 6);





        }
        Gl.glEnd();


        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
        {
            //Merah Tengah
            Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 6);
            Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 6);

            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), (3) * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), (3) * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3);


        }
        Gl.glEnd();

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
        {
            //PUTIH Belakang
            Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -20);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), -20);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();



        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
        {
            //putih alas Belakang
            Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -20);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl + 20), -20);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl + 20), -25);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();



        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
        for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 360); iogl = (iogl + 90))
        {
            Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, -25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(0, 10 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -17);
            Gl.glVertex3f(10 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 0, -25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, -25);
            Gl.glVertex3f(10 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 0, -17);
            Gl.glVertex3f(0, 10 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -25);
        }
        Gl.glEnd();
```

here the screenshot where the object is a x position, i want make it (standing) at y position what should i add to code

[ScreenShot](https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11141204_1587820734809144_8706510776903265443_n.jpg?oh=bf2d7273ddf08124478e32cf5bbdf9ba&oe=55DF0174)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to rotate your rocket 90 degree around Z axis to make it stand on y axis.

If you put this line at the beginning of code you posted, it should work.

```
GL.Rotate(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to [glTranslatef](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) function at the beginning. That would multiply the matrix and everything you draw will be relative to the translated coordinates.